# Why won't my HTML template display images/external css for definitions in my controller in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Problem after problem haha, but I'm so close to finishing my project!!

So I have my Ruby on Rails program done and working. Now i'm trying to integrate it into an HTML template..

I finally got the graphics and template to load properly, but only for the index.html.erb page since that's the starting page. Now my problem is the page defined as "**result**" from my controller file, won't display properly. It looks like it may be an easy fix, but not sure how. It looks like the inline css styles are working properly based on the format of **result**, but the images and styling in my style.css aren't loading for the template now (other than for index).

I put the images directory as a sub directory of public. I have style.css in public as well.

I have a page in views called "**customerdisplay.html.erb**," which contains the HTML coding for my template. One of the div tags in that file is a custom div in my external stylesheet, but when I use that tag, I also set the align to center. The centering works, but everything else from the external stylesheet isn't working.

**I'll add the controller code and the view code for reference.**

---

### My question:

**How can I get the external stylesheet and images to work for "def result" in my controller file?**

---

### myRuby_controller.rb

```
class MyRubyController < ApplicationController
  def index
# the first user screen is displayed:
# index.html.erb in views/myRuby directory
    # This controller is executed
  end

def result
    # when the user presses submit, result is called
@data = params[:data] # The data text field 
    @field = params[:field] # the request
    # check for nondigits in the data
   
    if @data =~ /\D/ 
       # if a nondigit, invalid.html.erb is displayed
       render :action => 'invalid' 
    else  # valid data 
    case @field   # check the request
        when  "cu" then  # customer data request
           # Verify that customer is in the customer table
           if Customer.exists?(@data) 
             # exists, display custdisply.html.erb
             render :action => 'custdisplay'
           else
             # does not, display notfound.html.erb
             render :action => 'notfound'
           end
        when "sr" then   # sales rep request
            if Customer.exists?(@data)
                         # exists, display salesrepdisplay.html.erb
                             render :action => 'salesrepdisplay'
                       else
                         # does not, display notfound.html.erb
                             render :action => 'notfound'
                       end

        when "or" then  #orders request
            if Customer.exists?(@data)
                         # exists, display orderdisplay.html.erb
                             render :action => 'orderdisplay'
                       else
                         # does not, display notfound.html.erb
                             render :action => 'notfound'
                       end

        when "p" then  #parts request
                        if Customer.exists?(@data)
                         # exists, display partsdisplay.html.erb
                             render :action => 'partsdisplay'
                       else
                         # does not, display notfound.html.erb
                             render :action => 'notfound'
                       end

    end  # end case

     end # end if valid data        

   end
   def custdisplay
   end
   def salesrepdisplay
   end
   def orderdisplay
   end
   def partsdisplay
   end
   def notfound
   end
   def invalid
   end
end
```

---

### views/customerdisplay.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>The Justin Geis Data Access Program</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="logo"><img src="images/logo.png"></div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
    <!--blank.. could add stuff if wanted.. --> 
    </div>
        
        <div id="content" align="center">
        <h1>Spartan Hardware Data Access</h1>
        <%  # get the customer data from the customer table
@custdata = Customer.find(@data)
# copy each field into a variable for display
@id = @custdata.id
@ln = @custdata.last_name
@fn = @custdata.first_name
@bl = @custdata.balance;
@bl = sprintf("%7.2f",@bl) # format as currency
@cl = @custdata.credit_limit
@cl = sprintf("%7.2f",@cl) # format as currency
@sr = @custdata.sales_rep

%>
<h1>customer data for customer: <%=@data %></h1>
<table border=1>
        <tr>
          <td>ID</td>
          <td>Last name</td>
          <td>First name</td>
          <td>Balance</td>
          <td>Credit limit</td>
          <td>Sales rep</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><%=@id%></td>
          <td><%=@ln%></td>
          <td><%=@fn%></td>
          <td><%=@bl%></td>
          <td><%=@cl%></td>
          <td><%=@sr%></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"><!--nothing right now --></div>
    
    </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

---

### Please let me know if you have any questions. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeBarwick what? HTML emails? Result is defined in the main controller. So after an option is selected from the form and "submit" is hit.. it basically creates a temporary page called "result" and redirects to it. So the url then look like http://www.(domainName).com/myRuby/result

Comment: Fudge...misread...through a blank #IGNORE ;P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view is being rendered inside another view, called a layout, usually in a file `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`. That's why your `<head>` won't work, because it's inside a `<body>`.

2 options:

1. Do it the Rails way and link your stuff from the layout, or alternatively have a `yield` in the layout that yields a tag from a `content_for` inside your `salesrepdisplay` view. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for
2. Instead of `render :action => 'salesrepdisplay'`, use `render :action => 'salesrepdisplay', :layout => nil`

Comment: I did option 2 since the first option is more confusing lol. But I did that and it's still not displaying the images/styles

Comment: Your stylesheet link is relative `href="style.css"`, so it depends on where your page is, whether your `style.css` is in `public/` or generated from `app/assets`. I strongly recommend doing it the Rails way, by first reading the official layout and views guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: Well this is just the extra credit part of my program, so I was trying to do it quickly :/ is there a quick way to get it to work?

Comment: Found a quick fix. I just added "../" haha